# C Array loop through

Tags: c, arrays

Instead of looping through each element of an array is it possible to loop through only elements which have assignments?

In the following example I would like to loop through only three elements instead of looping through each element in the array. What are my options ? I hate to loop through thousands of elements when only handful from them are assigned based on certain logic.

```
main()
{
    int i, intArray[10000];
    intArray[334] = 30;
    intArray[563] = 50;
    intArray[989] = 90;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
      printf("%d\n", intArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading the post. Sorry if it a re-post. I would not find similar question in the forum.

Comment: Google "sparse arrays"

Comment: Is this for performance, or just to avoid printing so much? Is there a value you could consider to be invalid? If the problem is just printing a lot, if you had an invalid value, you could do, `if (intArray[i] == invalidVal) { continue; }`

Answer (score 6):

Only indirectly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, intArray[10000];
    int active[10000];
    int n_active = 0;
    intArray[334] = 30;
    active[n_active++] = 334;
    intArray[563] = 50;
    active[n_active++] = 563;
    intArray[989] = 90;
    active[n_active++] = 989;

    for (i = 0; i < n_active; i++)
      printf("%d\n", intArray[active[i]]);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, more succinctly but not more clearly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, intArray[10000];
    int active[10000];
    int n_active = 0;
    intArray[active[n_active++]=334] = 30;
    intArray[active[n_active++]=563] = 50;
    intArray[active[n_active++]=989] = 90;

    for (i = 0; i < n_active; i++)
      printf("%d\n", intArray[active[i]]);
    return 0;
}
```

Both of these programs will suffer if there's more than one assignment to the same index (that index will be stored in the `active` array twice).  As it stands, it also doesn't check for overflow of the `active` array (but that shouldn't be a problem; the hypothesis is that only a few of the rows are populated), and the indexes are stored in the order that they're presented — not in key order.  All these defects can be fixed, but take more code (it would probably need to be a function or two).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
# include <stdio.h>
int totalElements = 0;
struct 
{
   int index, data;
} Data[10000];

void addElement(int index, int data)
{
   Data[totalElements].data = data;
   Data[totalElements++].index = index;
}

main()
{
   int i;
   addElement(334, 30);
   addElement(563, 50);
   addElement(989, 90);
   for (i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
   {
      printf("%d %d\n", Data[i].data, Data[i].index);
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
30 334
50 563
90 989
```

This also suffers the same limitations Jonathan Leffler mentioned.

**EDIT**

```
# include <stdio.h>
int totalElements = 0;
struct
{
   int index, currentElement = 0, data[100];
} Data[10000];

void addElement(int index, int data)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
   {
      if (Data[i].index == index)
      {
         Data[i].data[Data[i].currentElement++] = data;
         return;
      }
   }
   Data[totalElements].data[Data[totalElements].currentElement++] = data;
   Data[totalElements++].index = index;
}

main()
{
   int i, j;
   addElement(334, 30);
   addElement(334, 40);
   addElement(563, 50);
   addElement(563, 60);
   addElement(989, 80);
   addElement(989, 90);
   for (i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < Data[i].currentElement; j++)
      {
         printf("%d %d\n", Data[i].index, Data[i].data[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
334 30
334 40
563 50
563 60
989 80
989 90
```

Using this idea you can overcome the limitations mentioned by Jonathan Leffler.

Comment: I like your first solution, but the edit solves the wrong problem. To resemble the simple array from the question, it should just overwrite the value in a specific position instead of inserting it in order. Besides, maybe you should mention that the second solution uses 101 times more memory than the original.

Comment: The limitation Jonathan mentioned was same indices storing multiple values. I believe that is what the second solution solves.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a different data structure, like a linked list. Each node in the list could have two `int` values, one could be the index and the other the value. The linked list would then only contain indicies which have been assigned (and you could also have value==0, if that is somehow different to the normal, unassigned index).

The other alternative would be to use something like a Dictionary structure. There are probably Dictionary implementations for C - I would say though, if C++ is available maybe you should use it instead (unless you are specifically trying to learn or are constrained to C) - C++ has many data types available straight out of the box.